# How do I calculate the 2nd term of continued fraction for the power tower ${^5}e=e^{e^{e^{e^{e}}}}$

Tags: numerical-methods, exponentiation, continued-fractions, tetration, big-numbers

I need to find the 2nd term of [continued fraction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFraction.html) for the [power tower](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html) ${^5}e=e^{e^{e^{e^{e}}}}$ ( i.e. $\lfloor\{e^{e^{e^{e^{e}}}}\}^{-1}\rfloor$), or even higher towers. The number is too big to process in reasonable time with numerical libraries or algorithms known to me — the 1st term of the continued fraction has more than $10^{10^6}$ decimal digits. Is there a trick that allows to do such calculations faster?

UPDATE: I created a sequence [A225053](http://oeis.org/A225053) in OEIS for 2nd terms of continued fractions for power towers $e,\,e^e,\,e^{e^e},\,\dots$ Please feel free to extend it if you find a way to calculate further terms.

Comment: Have you looked at Euler's continued fraction formula for the exponential function? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula#The_exponential_function It probably won't help you get an exact answer, but it may show you that it's not 0.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It might be not a direct answer to your question, but it is possible that there is **no 2nd term** of the continued fraction in question.

I believe it is a long-standing open problem if $\,{^5 e}\in\mathbb{N}$, and, in general, for every integer $n \ge 5$, if $\,{^n e}\in\mathbb{N}$ (and also, for every integer $n \ge 4$, if $\,{^n \pi}\in\mathbb{N}$).

It is mentioned multiple times in Wikipedia, e.g. in Russian Wikipedia article [Открытые математические проблемы](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B#.D0.92.D0.BE.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.8B_.D0.B8.D1.80.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8) (Open mathematical problems) and on some mailing lists. Similar questions were discussed here on Math.SE: [$e^{e^{e^{79}}}$ and ultrafinitism](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/13052/75621), [How to show $e^{e^{e^{79}}}$ is not an integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13054/how-to-show-eee79-is-not-an-integer). Currently these questions look very far from being resolved and it is completely unclear how to approach them.

Comment: I wonder, does anybody really believe it can be an integer?